Boostrap Modal Not Operating (BS v4.5) Flask
I have been attempting to implement modals for the Edit and Create functionality for a basic CRUD website using Flask and SQLAlchemy, to no avail. The buttons do nothing when pressed.
I have gone through several iterations of HTML, using Bulma and Bootstrap to no improvement. I have tried multiple browsers in case it was due to a pop-up blocker of some kind as well.
Movies.html:5
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalcreate">Add New Review</button>

Movies.html:24
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-  target="#modaledit">Edit</button>
</td>

Modals as appears in Movies.html:
<div class="modal fade" id="modaledit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Movie Review</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-genre" class="col-form-label">Genre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="genre"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-director" class="col-form-label">Director</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="director"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-franchise" class="col-form-label">Franchise</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="franchise"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-rating" class="col-form-label">Rating</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rating"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalcreate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create New Movie Review</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ url_for('create_movie') }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-genre" class="col-form-label">Genre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="genre"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-director" class="col-form-label">Director</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="director"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-franchise" class="col-form-label">Franchise</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="franchise"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="movie-rating" class="col-form-label">Rating</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rating"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZSTVPPVoK4Z83IYJM5lYjWPG+YtF/er1z+LcbL5ZCVXDD9dZsiqFT+0OAlaTWfAA"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+Knujsl5+gbgxc5wc9eVkRx03WO6c6lvz0Ww53cu1WM+xXv"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

App Routing for Movies View:
@app.route("/movies/")
def movies():
    movies = Movies.query.all()
    return render_template('movies.html', movies=movies)

@app.route('/create_movie', methods = ['POST'])
def create_movie():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        genre = request.form['genre']
        director = request.form['director']
        franchise = request.form['franchise']
        rating = request.form['rating']

        new_movie = Movies(title, genre, director, franchise, rating)
        db.session.add(new_movie)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('movies'))

